# How to use python to see if values of column A are in column B, if not append rows to the table?

Tags: python, compare, multiple-columns

so I have 2 sheets, sheet 1 and sheet 2. I want to see if 'Projects' of sheet 1 are in 'Projects' of sheet 2, if not I want to append these projects to sheet 1, seems simple but I can't figure it out, I'm a beginner on it would be highly appreciated if somebody can help me out to do it in python!!

Comment: sorry for confusion, I want to do this in python, not excel

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using pandas, you could do the following to get a column with all unique projects:

```
import pandas as pd

projects = pd.concat([df1["Projects"], df2["Projects"]]).unique()
```

This is when you only want to have a column with all unique projects. If you have other columns in the DataFrames as well which you want to combine, I'd suggest to perform an outer join the DataFrames. You can do this as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

full_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Projects',how='outer')
```

For more information on how joins work, [you could check this blogpost.](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/02/joins-in-pandas-master-the-different-types-of-joins-in-python/)

Hope this helps!